# How to output formatted text from list of values from JSON?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, slack, slack-api

I am working on a slackbot. I have a json file and python code that outputs something to slack based on the user's input. There is a search command that outputs search results from a json file. The current output is not formatted because when the values are taken from the json, they are appended to a list and then returned to the main python program.

I have tried creating a loop that would kind of parse through the search output and cut it down so that each set of values are separate and then added to a list that can be formatted. The loop I tried doesn't really work, and I'm not too sure how to properly make a loop that I can use to format the output. I have also tried formatting the output using format(), but it doesn't work because it is a list.

This is the an example of the current search output.

```
if command.startswith(SEARCH):
        try:
            search = search_data(command.split(' ')[1])
            response = search
        except KeyError:
            response = 'This search key does not exist.'
        except TypeError:
            response = 'Wrong search input'
```

This is an example search command that I import from another python script:

```
def search_data(keyword):

result = []
for key, value in data.items():
    first = value['first']
    last = value['last']
    if keyword in first:
        result.append(value)
    elif keyword in last:
        result.append(value)
return result
```

This is an example JSON:

```
{
"1": {
  "id": "1",
  "first": "Joe",
  "last": "Adam"
},
"2": {
  "id": "2",
  "first": "Mary",
  "last": "Smith"
},
"3": {
    "id": "3",
    "first": "Ann",
    "last": "John"
}
}
```

I have another output which I format using this line of code and I want to format my list output the same way.

```
response = '*ID:* {}\n *First:* {}\n *Last:*
{}\n\n'.format(search['id'],search['first'],search['last'])
```

The expected output is for the user to enter a search in slack using the slackbot. The user can input "search J" for example and the output lists the matching set of values that have a J in either the "first" or "last" values. My current output is something like:

```
[{"id":"1","first":"Joe","last":"Adam"}, 
{"id":"2","first":"Ann","last":"John"}]
```

but I want to format it like:

```
ID: 1
First: Joe
Last: Adam

ID: 2
First: Ann
Last: John
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do it

```
"\n\n".join([f"ID: {out['id']}\nFirst: {out['first']}\nLast: {out['last']}" for out in result])
```

Comment: Omg that works. Thanks so much. I changed "result" to "search" and fit it in my code and it works perfectly. I was bashing my head trying to figure this out. Can you possibly explain what the f is after join?

Comment: the `f""` string is a formatted string. where there are `{` `}` inside the string, python will treat whatever inside them as variables. this is like using `str.format()` function, but instead of passing variables to `format()` this will just put them inside the string.